# Nginx in Ubuntu doesn't have access to a ssl certificate

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, https

I've generated a certificate on Ubuntu 16 and I'm trying to run nginx and get this:

```
$ nginx -t

nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
nginx: [emerg] BIO_new_file("/etc/letsencrypt/live/my_website.com/fullchain.pem") failed (SSL: error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/my_website.com/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

That certifate has the standard permissions `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root`. But why isn't it accessible for nginx? Of course, I can do `chmod 755` but would that be the right thing to do?

After restart nginx is working and my website too, but `nginx -t` still returns the same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be running `nginx -t` as an unprivileged user.

To test your nginx configuration, instead try:

```
$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

or, if `sudo` is unavailable:

```
$ su -
Password:
# nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Answer (score 0):

It must be accessible via nginx user or group like www-data. It means user who started nginx.

Try:

```
# setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rx /etc/letsencrypt/
```

Comment: the same error still

Comment: I checked /etc/letsencrypt permissions on my server and owner of all files is root, no ACL's etc. In task list only one of Apache processes is started as root, other as www-data. I don't know how to do that with nginx.

My only idea is setting ACL's like that: 

    setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rx /etc/letsencrypt/

In your case it might be other user, but for me it is www-data.